# Tweaking the cursor in gVim

Tags: gvim, cursor

I'd like to change the appearance of my cursor to something similar to this picture:
[image: image showing a cursor with a yellow underscore and a block background differing from the editor background]

How can I have `_` in the cursor, and how do I change the color of the cursor?

Comment: Check this out -> [https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153774/4838158](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16153774/4838158) And of course, `:h guicursor`

Comment: Thanks, follow your suggestions. `h guicursor` options change shape of cursor follow percent of char. So the expected cursor as pic should be block but how we can have `_` in that block and even color it?

Comment: `:h highlight` seems can't do the trick because I can't find any related Cursor color options that affect `unknown defined` `_`.

Answer (score 2):

For your cursor in insert mode and command-line insert mode use the following:

```
set guicursor=i-ci:hor10-Search
```

- `i-ci` : insert and  command-line insert
- `hor10`: Horizontal bar, 10% of height
- `Search`: Yellow, the background color from the "Search" highlight group.